# Spark Streaming checkpoint to remote hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I am trying to checkpoint my spark streaming context to hdfs to handle a failure at some point of my application. I have my HDFS setup on a separate cluster and spark running on a separate standalone server. To do this, I am using :

```
ssc.checkpoint(directory: String)
```

This gives me : `org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=WRITE` when I try with directory as `"hdfs://hostname:port/pathToFolder"`

How can I checkpoint to a remote hdfs path? Is it possible to add credentials to the string uri? I tried googling, but no help so far.

Thanks and appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried "hdfs://username:password@hostname:port/pathToFolder"?

Comment: great! I'll put that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide the credentials by using:

```
hdfs://username:password@hostname:port/pathToFolder
```